# how to use autoTyping.js in react jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I making a portfolio, and i want to apply animation on my name by adding the popular auto typing affect, changing my name to various other strings like fullstack, frontend,..etc.

I found [this](https://github.com/tsanak/autotyping) lightweight library that creates animated typing effects, but i dont know how to properly implement the script into my jsx file. I tried this below but i can't render the animation at all.

These are my attempts so far:

1. I Created src/autotyping.js file:

```
var AutoTyping = function (e) { var t = {}; function r(n) { if (t[n])
//...

const exampleText = ['Fullstack.', 'FrontEnd', 'BackEnd', 'Designer'];
const exampleTyping = new AutoTyping('#text', exampleText, {
    typeSpeed: 50,
    deleteSpeed: 50,
    waitBeforeDelete: 2000,
    waitBetweenWords: 500,
});
exampleTyping.start()
```

2. In jsx file where i want to render the animation:

```
import { autotyping } from "./../../autotyping";

const About= () => {
return (

<p id="text" class="text-red-500">
   <autotyping>
      <script src="./../../autotyping" type="text/javascript"/>
   </autotyping>
</p>

)}
```

Comment: i tried to use this library and i made a costum js and configured it, but i dont know where should i put this line `<script src='path/to/AutoTyping.min.js'></script>`

Comment: and should i wrap the <script> tag the whole <p> ?

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/ you should read some react tutorials first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run any imperative code inside `useEffect`

The component

```
const AutoTyping = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const exampleText = ['Fullstack.', 'FrontEnd', 'BackEnd', 'Designer'];
    const exampleTyping = new AutoTyping('#text', exampleText, {
      typeSpeed: 50,
      deleteSpeed: 50,
      waitBeforeDelete: 2000,
      waitBetweenWords: 500,
    });
    exampleTyping.start()
  })
}
```

Usage

```
const About = () => {
  return (
    <p id="text" class="text-red-500">
      <AutoTyping />
    </p>
  )
}
```

To load the component, add script tag to the HTML, don't inset it into jsx

Comment: i added the useeffect hook and added the <script> header section in public/index.html, and in jsx render i changed the word Fullstack to <AutoTyping />. Once i do this my site change to blank !

Comment: You have errors in the console that you should read